# Grep out the last matching line of a text file which line contains a given string, and doesn't start with another string

Tags: bash, perl, logging, grep, pcre

I would like to analyze a log file, and grepping for an IP address. Log file looks like:

```
<date> -> <IP address>
```

for example:

```
2016-06-02 11:46:33 +0200 -> 86.171.55.134
```

So I would like to select the last line which contains a given IP, and the line doesn't start with the today date (2016-06-02), my first attempt unfortunately doesn't work:

```
tac logfile.txt|grep -P  '^(?<!2016-06-03).*?86.171.55.134'
```

This way I succeeded to make it work, but I would like to work out a more general way, where I can use .* or .*? instead of 19 points, because sometimes there are more and unknown length data between the two pattern:

```
tac logfile.txt|grep -aP -m1 '(?<!2016\-06\-03)...................86.171.55.134'
```

Here 5000 actual line of log data to play with:

http://www.filefactory.com/file/2sdj77aqflxp/5000.txt

Only the IP addresses were faked.

Comment: try to provide a [mcve] because this is too little to start playing with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^(?<!2016-06-03).*?86.171.55.134` this regex will never work, lets break it down to understand:

```
^                # Start of line
 (?<!2016-06-03) # Negative look behind searching for 2016-06-03
```

Can there be anything before start of line?

You might want to try to change it to a look ahead:

```
tac logfile.txt | grep -P '^(?!2016-06-03).*?86.171.55.134'
```

Or with sed:

```
tac logfile.txt | sed -n '/^2016-06-03/!{/86\.171\.55\.134/p}'
```

And if you only want the first (last because of `tac`) match:

```
tac logfile.txt | sed -n '/^2016-06-03/!{/86\.171\.55\.134/{p;q}}'
```

Comment: sed method works, grep method doesn't, it prints a line which starts with the non needed date.

Comment: before the date string there is nothing, it's the start of the line.

Comment: @Konstantin What is it that doesn't work with the grep?

Comment: It printed a lot of lines with an improper date. Sed solution was even faster.

Answer (score 0):

This will grep for the lines having IP in it, and then remove the lines having todays date. (Generalized way) and head to chop only the first one of it.

```
tac data |grep  "86.171.55.134" |grep -v "`date +%Y-%m-%d`" |head -1
2016-06-02 11:46:33 +0200 -> 86.171.55.134
```